# MySQL: Subqueries with multiple results

Tags: mysql, subquery, contains

I can't find the error in my (my)sql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   KUNDEN 
WHERE  KUNR IN (SELECT DISTINCT KUNR 
                FROM   AUSLEIHE)
```

kunr: integer

Everytime it says, that there are **multiple results in the subquery**. But my target is to check, if the subquery contains the value of kunr.
It would be very nice, if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM   KUNDEN  k 
JOIN AUSLEIHE a ON (k.KUNR  = a.KUNR )
```

Comment: It works!! I read something about set theory when I tried to understand the join statement. Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT KUNR 
FROM   AUSLEIHE GROUP BY KUNR)
```

Try this subquery.

Answer (score 0):

just for laughs

```
SELECT * FROM   KUNDEN  k 
LEFT JOIN AUSLEIHE a ON (k.KUNR  = a.KUNR )
where   a.KUNR is not null
```